# State variable is changing when accessed from useEffect()

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am declaring a new variable called name and initializing it with useState to Math.Random() I then log the variable in 2 places, once in the body of the component, and once in the useEfect of the component. What I'm seeing is that the variable is changing.

My name is 0.1869175357793944 here
My name is 0.10608469707774937 after render

Am I doing something wrong here? I cannot figure out why it's behaving like this.

Here is my code:

```js
const {useState} = React;
const {useEffect} = React;

const Example = () => {
  const [name, setName] = useState(Math.random());
  console.log(`My name is ${name} here`);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(`My name is ${name} after render`);
  }, [])

  return (
    <div>Look at console</div>
  );
};

// Render it
ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
  <Example/>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById("react")
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.development.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.development.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```

Comment: Maybe you have a specific case. But why not set the state/number in useEffect. would not that solve your problem?

Comment: Well, the console log in the component body is an unintentional side-effect, so what it logs out isn't very valid. What is logged out from the `useEffect` is/was the value from the render cycle. What is your *actual* problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are seeing is an unintentional side-effect from the console.log in the component body. When you render your app inside a `React.StrictMode` component some functions are double-invoked to help you detect these unexpected side-effects.

```
const Example = () => {
  const [name, setName] = useState(Math.random());
  console.log(`My name is ${name} here`); // <-- unexpected side effect!!

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(`My name is ${name} after render`);
  }, [])

  return (
    <div>Look at console</div>
  );
};
```

[StrictMode - Detecting Unexpected Side Effects](https://reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html#detecting-unexpected-side-effects)

> Strict mode can’t automatically detect side effects for you, but it
> can help you spot them by making them a little more deterministic.
> This is done by intentionally double-invoking the following functions:
>
> - Class component `constructor`, `render`, and `shouldComponentUpdate` methods
> - Class component static `getDerivedStateFromProps` method
> - ***Function component bodies*** (*emphasis mine*)
> - State updater functions (the first argument to `setState`)
> - Functions passed to `useState`, `useMemo`, or `useReducer`

Additionally

> **Note:**
>
> Starting with React 17, React automatically modifies the console
> methods like `console.log()` to silence the logs in the second call to
> lifecycle functions. However, it may cause undesired behavior in
> certain cases where [a workaround can be used](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/20090#issuecomment-715927125).

The additional note explains why you only see ***ONE*** `"My name is 0.1869175357793944 here"` log instead of two, each with a *different* random number value.

Here's a codesandbox running React v16.13.0 where the second log has not been stifled yet. Notice two unexpected logs with different values. Notice also that the result of the second call is that you see when the component *actually* rendered, i.e. what you see logged in the `useEffect` hook.

[image: Edit state-variable-is-changing-when-accessed-from-useeffect]

> ```
> My name is 0.859128653421811 here 
> My name is 0.6861295664325067 here 
> My name is 0.6861295664325067 after render
> ```

Comment: is this design a problem? Should I avoid this pattern?

Comment: @hcham1 "Should I avoid this pattern?" Generally, yes... you don't want unintentional side-effects in your code, that's what `useEffect` hook is for. If you are only console logging values for testing, then it's probably fine so long as you understand what is happening. Imagine if instead of a console log you were creating socket connections or subscriptions and never cleaning them up... resource leak.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, this behavior will only happen in the development mode, not in production. In production, it will show a single value.

Reason: React applications are wrapped with `<React.StrictMode />` component.

In short, strict mode help to cache any issue that occurs during development.

> Note:
> Strict mode checks are run in development mode only; they do not impact the production build. https://reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html

**Just for testing**, try to remove `<React.StrictMode>...</React.StrictMode>`. Your problem will not exist anymore in the development mode as well.

```
 ReactDOM.render(
  <Example/>
  document.getElementById("react")
);
```

Comment: "Your problem will not exist anymore in the development mode as well." isn't accurate... the problem will certainly still exist, you just won't get a nice indication of the unexpected behavior.

Comment: haha, true the problem will stay as it is. But it will not be visible anymore :)

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is that you are assigning `name` a value of the `Math.random` function instead of the result of `Math.random()`.

Try this:

```
const [name, setName] = useState(Math.random());
```

Comment: That's not the problem unfortunately. I updated the code snippet to Math.random() so you can see it still behaves the same way

Comment: That seems strange. Did you fully reload your app after making that change? I've noticed state can be a little "sticky" with the dev server hot reload

Comment: My only other thought was what Muhammad posted - initialize a `const` with `Math.random()` first, then initialize your state with that. It seems like that shouldn't be necessary though

Comment: yes i have a separate app that i am testing with and the issue persists with Math.random(). I tried Muhammed's answer and commented on it. While it does solve the apparent issue, it's not ideal since now all Example components would have the same name which is unintended.

Answer (score 0):

I don't sure but it may work for you

```
const {useState} = React;
const {useEffect} = React;
const number=Math.random()
const Example = () => {
  const [name, setName] = useState(number);
  console.log(`My name is ${name} here`);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(`My name is ${name} after render`);
  }, [])

  return (
    <div>Look at console</div>
  );
};

// Render it
ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
  <Example/>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById("react")
);
```

Comment: while this does partially solve the issue, now every Example component would have the same name since it's global

Comment: you can pass number in the props for every Example compnent like
<Example number={Math.random()} />
and use cost Example=(number)=>{
const [name,setName]=useState(number)
.....
....
}

Comment: If you move `const number=Math.random()` inside the `Example` function (right before the `useState` call), it should then be local to each instance of `Example`